# E: The package aftershot2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: server, package-management, xubuntu, software-center

Can someone please tell me how to fix this I'm running the latest xubuntu and the ubuntu software center keeps freezing. I can't get the new update. I've tried downloading the sympatic packager but it didn't work because the store keeps freezing. help please the terminal error is the title.

Answer (score 0):

aftershot2? It is some proprietary manually installed package.

Try to remove it if you don't need it:

```
sudo apt-get remove aftershot2
```